# Нужна ли запятая после тире?

Tags: запятые, тире

> Жаль он не знал, что описываемое событие(,)(-)это выдумка.

И нужно ли там тире?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире, конечно, нужно, оно ставится перед словом "это". А запятая не нужна вот почему:
*описываемое событие — это выдумка* (то есть ничего не нужно закрывать запятой).

После "жаль" (вводное слово) нужна запятая.